# how to get the count of eventTime with the same timestamp from a column which has list of events in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is an example of my dataframe. i have events in a list within a column of a dataframe.  I have to get the count of events where the eventDateTime is duplicated. how can I do it?
i am not able to use value_counts with in the list of events.
| deviceId | insertTime  | events |

```
    |1234567   |1686261264478| [{'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261000937', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436213', 'longitude': '-90.5173831'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261001954', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436203', 'longitude': '-90.5172008'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261002963', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.043618', 'longitude': '-90.5169604'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261003971', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436147', 'longitude': '-90.5167171'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261004989', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436122', 'longitude': '-90.5164759'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261006007', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436088', 'longitude': '-90.516233'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261007015', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436047', 'longitude': '-90.5159967'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261008032', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436036', 'longitude': '-90.515768'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261009049', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436022', 'longitude': '-90.5155419'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261010068', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.043602', 'longitude': '-90.5153184'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261011083', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436021', 'longitude': '-90.5150956'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261012094', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436028', 'longitude': '-90.5148754'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261013110', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436024', 'longitude': '-90.5146568'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261014120', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436006', 'longitude': '-90.5138385'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261015136', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435985', 'longitude': '-90.5142199'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261016146', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435974', 'longitude': '-90.514005'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261017165', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435972', 'longitude': '-90.51379'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261018172', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435965', 'longitude': '-90.513576'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261019191', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435963', 'longitude': '-90.5133605'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261020209', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435954', 'longitude': '-90.5131474'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '1234567'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261021215', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435946', 'longitude': '-90.5129359’}}]|
**second row**
|456789   |1686261264478| [{'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261000937', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436213', 'longitude': '-90.5173831'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261001954', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436203', 'longitude': '-90.5172008'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261002963', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.043618', 'longitude': '-90.5169604'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261003971', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436147', 'longitude': '-90.5167171'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261004989', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436122', 'longitude': '-90.5164759'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261006007', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436088', 'longitude': '-90.516233'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261007015', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436047', 'longitude': '-90.5159967'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261008032', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436036', 'longitude': '-90.515768'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261009049', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436022', 'longitude': '-90.5155419'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261010068', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.043602', 'longitude': '-90.5153184'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261011083', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436021', 'longitude': '-90.5150956'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261012094', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436028', 'longitude': '-90.5148754'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261013110', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436024', 'longitude': '-90.5146568'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261014120', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0436006', 'longitude': '-90.5138385'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261015136', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435985', 'longitude': '-90.5142199'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261016146', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435974', 'longitude': '-90.514005'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261017165', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435972', 'longitude': '-90.51379'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261018172', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435965', 'longitude': '-90.513576'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261019191', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435963', 'longitude': '-90.5133605'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261020209', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435954', 'longitude': '-90.5131474'}}, {'deviceDetailsDataModel': {'deviceId': '456789'}, 'eventDateTime': '1686261021215', 'gpsDataModel': {'latitude': '38.0435946', 'longitude': '-90.5129359’}}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *"extract"* the value of `eventDateTime` from the column, explode the dataframe and then use `.value_counts()`:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

# apply literal eval if necessary:
df["events"] = df["events"].apply(literal_eval)

df["eventDateTime"] = df["events"].apply(lambda x: [d["eventDateTime"] for d in x])
df = df.explode("eventDateTime")

print(df["eventDateTime"].value_counts())
```

Prints:

```
eventDateTime
1686261000937    2
1686261012094    2
1686261020209    2
1686261019191    2
1686261018172    2
1686261017165    2
1686261016146    2
1686261015136    2

...
```

---

EDIT: If you want to show result grouped by `deviceId`:

```py
print(df.groupby("deviceId")["eventDateTime"].value_counts())
```

Prints:

```
deviceId  eventDateTime
456789    1686261000937    1
          1686261001954    1
          1686261021215    1
          1686261020209    1
          1686261002963    1
          1686261003971    1
          1686261004989    1
          1686261006007    1
          1686261007015    1
          1686261008032    1
          1686261009049    1
          1686261010068    1
          1686261011083    1
          1686261012094    1
          1686261013110    1
          1686261014120    1
          1686261015136    1
          1686261016146    1
          1686261017165    1
          1686261018172    1
          1686261019191    1
1234567   1686261011083    1
          1686261002963    1
          1686261003971    1
          1686261004989    1
          1686261006007    1
          1686261007015    1
          1686261008032    1
          1686261009049    1
          1686261010068    1
          1686261012094    1
          1686261013110    1
          1686261014120    1
          1686261015136    1
          1686261016146    1
          1686261017165    1
          1686261018172    1
          1686261019191    1
          1686261020209    1
          1686261001954    1
          1686261000937    1
          1686261021215    1
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked i want to show the result by the deviceId . how can i do that?

Comment: @sman If I understand you correctly, you can use `.groupby` (see my edit).

Comment: thanks it worked. can you explain the lambda function?

Comment: @sman The lambda function creates new list, where I extract the `eventDateTime` from the dictionaries that are stored in `events` column. Then I'm using `.explode()` to transform each element of these lists to rows.

Comment: the events has gpsDataModelwith latitude and longitude. how can i get the latitude and longitude value counts to see gps events are duplicated.